# ExpressJS req.user returning undefined?

Tags: node.js, express

user returning undefined? im so confused

```
export const getCurrentUser = async (req, res) => {
  // fetch user
  console.log(req.user)
  const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId })
  // fetch withdraws
  res.send({
    currentUser: user
  })
};
```

const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.userId })
^TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userId')

Answer (score -1):

You need to share more code. Error is thrown because req.user is undefined and you try to access property on undefined object. Look into middleware where req.user gets attached, since req.user is not natively attached to express request object. The problem is in middleware where req.user gets attached. Share middleware code if you want further help